# Is my signature off bc I'm using printHexBinary instead of encodeHexString?

Tags: java, apache, curl, hex, sign

The API documentation uses Hex.encodeHexString(), yet in this code I am using DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary() as I don't have Apache.

```
    String strForSign = "/v1/account/balance" + "/" + nonce + "/";
    String signatureStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(strForSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secretKeySpec);

    String signatureResult = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(signatureStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

The curl command that makes use of this signature:

```
String command = "curl -H \"KC-API-KEY: " + apiKey + "\" -H \"KC-API-NONCE: " + nonce + "\" -H \"KC-API-SIGNATURE: " + signature + 
        "\" -X GET \"https://api.kucoin.com/v1/account/balance/\"";
```

I should be getting my balance yet I keep getting

```
{"code":"UNAUTH","msg":"Signature verification failed","success":false,"timestamp":1547545347146}
```

Is this because Hex.encodeHexString() and DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary() produce different outputs here, or for some other reason?

Comment: Why do you base64 encode the data that is processed by the HMAC (the input data)? This is very unusual and may be your problem.

Comment: @Robert This code was essentially copied from [the java example in the API docs](https://kucoinapidocs.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/authentication/signature-calculation), save for the hex conversion at the end. Do you think they have it wrong? They have been known to be a little spotty in both their API and documentation.